# Is $A$ a convex set of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, complex-numbers, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Let us consider the following set
\begin{eqnarray*}
A
&=&\Big\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C};\;\exists x_n=(a_n,b_n)\in \mathbb{C}^2\,;\;\;\;|a_n+b_n|=1, \\
&&\phantom{++++++++++}\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow+\infty}|a_n|^2+a_n\overline{b_n}= \lambda\;\;\hbox{and}\;\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\longrightarrow+\infty}|a_n|<\infty\Big\}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Is $A$ a convex set of $\mathbb{C}$?

Thank you.

Comment: This should work pretty straightforward: take two arbitrary points of A, look at the straight line between the two points, write the points in the form with the limes, do a bit of calculation and try to find a new representation of this line that fits in the definition of A.

Comment: @RoyPJ We dont know it is convex or not. So going straightforward is false and may we dont get anything!

Comment: @GhD Of course we don't know that yet. But since (at least for me) it is hard to get an intuition of this set this is how I would proceed. On the way you will get a better understanding of the set and might find counterexamples (if existent). I think this is a better way than directly constructing examples and testing them.

Comment: @RoyPJ I see. You are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but if I take $a=\lambda$ and $b = 1-\lambda$, then $|a|^2+a\bar{b} = \lambda$, so it looks like this set is the whole plane.